# How are all LTI systems also dynamical systems?

Tags: control-engineering, dynamics

How are all LTI systems also dynamical systems?
I understand that LTI systems are linear and time invariant and that dynamical systems describe how one state develops into another, but how would this make all LTI systems dynamical systems?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the question is. IMO this is like asking "why are all green apples also apples?" Some dynamical systems are LTI, some are not. Just like some apples are red, i.e. not green.

Comment: Just a gain would also be a LTI system, but is not a dynamical system.

Answer (score 1):

*Dynamical Systems* are any systems that *change* with time. Real physical systems or system models. What is changing? Any variable within the system (examples, displacement, velocity, pH, sound intensity ...). They can be linear, nonlinear time varying or not, etc. So it's a very *broad* definition.

LTI systems are a *subset* of dynamical systems that are strictly linear and the parameters do not change with time. They are usually *models* of real systems. Real physical systems, if you look close enough are never linear. Parameters can change with temperature for example. So LTI 'models' better suited. They approximate dynamic systems that are near linear and time invariant.